# Thermostat not getting power (Nest E74)

Tags: heating, thermostat, furnace, cooling, nest

I replaced an old Honeywell thermostat about a month ago with a Nest thermostat. Friday Nest started displaying an E74 error.

I have two furnaces and two outdoor units, one for upstairs and for downstairs. Upstairs works fine, downstairs does not.

Both furnaces show “normal operation” LED codes.

There are W1, C, Y1, Rh and G wires.

I have done the following to check what was going on with no different result:

- Reinstalled old thermostat (no power if I remove batteries)
- Connected Rh to Rc
- Removed the C wire
- Removed the Y1 wire
- Made a connection with Rh to G to check if fan would come on
- Replaced fuse on furnace (both furnaces, they weren’t blown but thought I’d try anyway)
- Checked all breaker boxes, turned on and off repeatedly
- Checked incoming power to AC unit outside, read 249V.
- Recut and rewired Nest completely.

I have no idea what other steps to take, I am in Texas - it is currently relatively hot outside and I cannot find a professional until June 1st

Comment: Have you checked the low voltage transformer in the furnace?  Depending upon which furnace...most are 24volt.   They do fail.

Comment: I haven’t checked the low voltage transformer. I’m going to research how to do that and I’ll update in a little while.

Comment: You really need a meter, if you don't have one.  They aren't that expensive ($30 and up).  I like ones with an "amp clamp" which enables you to measure current (amps).  Don't bother with those proximity voltage testers, they can be easily misunderstood for those without much electrical experience.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter? If so, set it to AC volts and see if you can measure 24V between R and C

Comment: Hey 3ph.  I thought of that, but in the OP he said even when he reinstalled the old stat he had no power if he removed the batteries.  So I thought, let's start at the source and see if he has power off the transformer.  Still your suggestion is a good diagnostic step.

Comment: Googling a Nest E74 error brings up lots of results.   People replaced their old T-stat with a Nest and then it quit working.  Many ppl also said re-installing the old t-stat DID NOT work.  Something is going on here.  Could it be the nest is drawing so much power it is burning out the 24v transformers? Or other components in "power stealing mode"?

Comment: Here is a link that Google has to say about an E74 error:  https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9235307

Comment: I have a multimeter, I just have no idea how to use it so I have to look up how to do everything. Learning process in the end, I’m about to go check the transformer.

Comment: I went ahead and looked, got a reading of 27V which either means it’s getting too much or I’m doing something wrong (which is the most likely explanation).

Comment: 27 volts is fine, particularly if there is no load at all on it. So we now know the transformer is ok and that you have a different problem (wiring t-stat, control board, etc.) .  I don't know enough about HVAC, so maybe others who do could jump in and help.